# Fundamental Domain for Congruence (mod 2) Group

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, hyperbolic-geometry

How can I show that the area between the circles $|z|=1$, $|z+\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$,  $|z-\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$ in the upper-half plane (here's a [picture](http://tinyurl.com/n4akn7t)) is a fundamental domain for the Fuchsian group $\Gamma \leq PSL(2, \mathbb{R})$ consisting of integer matrices that are congruent to the identity mod 2.  I'm pretty sure I can show that this set contains a fundamental domain.  Now I need to show that no element of this set is translated into the set by an element of $\Gamma$. From the examples I've seen, it seems the proof of such things is usually annoyingly ad hoc. Also, if you have a better tag for this, please feel free to add it or to subtract an inappropriate tag.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the fundamental domaing for $\Gamma$ is bigger than this. An example of a fundamental domain is the area between the circles $|z+\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$, $|z−\frac{1}{2}|=\frac{1}{2}$ and the vertical lines at $-1$ and $1$.

One way to see this that your picture is not enough is that since it is an ideal triangle, it has area $\pi=\pi-(0+0+0)$ (this follows from Gauss-Bonnet). It is well knows that $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ has a fundamental domain of area $\frac{\pi}{3}$. It is also well known that the index of $\Gamma$ in $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$ is 6 (since $|PSL(2,\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})|=6$) so that necessarily, $\Gamma$ must have a fundamental domain of area $2\pi$.

Comment: lol thanks! how on earth did you find this question?

Comment: Honestly, I searched "congruence" and "hyperbolic" in the unanswered section because I was recently learning about principal congruence subgroups.